# Missing Icon for running Tests repeatedly in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, test-explorer

At the left side of Test Explorer there used to be an icon for running Tests repeatedly (an arrow curving upwards). It seems to be gone in Visual Studio 2015 - I am using Community Edition.
Can I get it back somehow?

Answer (score 0):

"Running unit tests after every build is supported in Visual Studio Enterprise." Reference: [Run unit tests with Test Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270865.aspx#BKMK_Run_tests_after_every_build).